# Как получить порядковый номер записи таблицы в PostgreSQL с учетом сортировки

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Hibernate 4.3.10.Final, Postgresql 9.4

Есть веб страница, в которую выводятся записи таблицы, также имеется пагинация. Записей в таблице может быть порядка миллиона. Записи выводятся по 20,50,100 штук, с учетом выставленных пользователем фильтров. Если пользователь добавил новую запись, она по аяксу улетает на сервер, сервер сохраняет эту запись в БД, теперь у нас есть id только что созданной записи и если мы узнаем какой по счету будет запись с этим id с учетом указанных сортировок, то сможем определить на какой странице будет эта запись, чтобы отдать клиенту только ее, и выставить фокус на эту новую запись.

Я погуглил и почитал, в основном люди пишут как просто проставить порядковые номера напротив записей в выдаче БД, но это что, для определения страницы нужно каждый раз дергать весь миллион записей?

Или подобную задачу как-то органично можно решить с помощью HQL?

**Дополнение.**

Миллион записей предполагается, но для теста еще не нагенерил их, не знаю как оно будет работать, но как "временное" решение вроде как можно воспользоваться подобным вложенным запросом

```
select * from (select row_number() over (order by last_name, first_name,
   middle_name) as number, c.* from myschema.table c) as output where output.id = 5
```

Comment: Могу предложить два альтернативных варианта, которые могут решить проблему, но ответом на вопрос не являются. 1 - После добавления новой записи, в AJAX-ответе возвращаете содержимое записи на клиентскую часть, добавляете на первое место в имеющемся списке и делаете её выбранной. Минус - при обновлении списка запись из него исчезнет. 2 - После добавления записи автоматически меняете фильтры пользователя так, чтобы отображалась только новая запись. Минус - такое поведение ПО пользователь вряд ли ожидает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С момента вопроса многое узнал о хибернейте, и похоже в коробке решения нет, поэтому вот пример решения:

```
select * from (select row_number() over (order by last_name, first_name, middle_name) as number, c.* from myschema.table c) as output where output.id = 5
```